# How to disable connected standby and hyper-v

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I want to have "sleep" mode that means I have to disable Hyper-V. At the same time, if Hyper-V is disabled Connected Standby will be enabled. This causes a huge battery drain for me through the night (11%).

As one is enabled when the other one is disabled and vice versa this annoys the hell out of me.

Is there a way to disable Hyper-V and disable connected standy, so that when my Surface Pro 3 i5, 256 GB, 8GB RAM is in sleep it truly sleeps?

I am open to all solutions... registry hack, etc.

Btw. hibernation is not an option for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to disable *Connected Standby* (or more precisely *InstantGo*) through a registry hack:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\CsEnabled
```

Change the value of this key to `0`, then restart.

One caveat here, while disabling InstantGo, you'll disable a regular *Sleep* too, because there is no traditional Sleep mode in the Surface Pro 3.

Additional info [here](http://www.surfaceforums.net/threads/disable-connected-standby.10901/).